# How to clean the voice mail in the notification screen?

Tags: notifications, samsung-galaxy-ace, notification-bar

How to clear the notification screen, without listening to the voice mail?

[image]

The phone is Galaxy Ace GT.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you have a **Clear** button in the top right corner?

This is what it looks like on my HTC Desire running Android 2.3.3.

[image: clear notifications]

What happens if you press and hold the voice mail? Do you get a menu to clear it out?

**Update:**

Tapping the notification dials the voice mail inbox, right? Unless you can tap and hold it to get a context menu from where you can remove it, then I'm afraid there's not much you can do about it.

I just talked to a Samsung rep and he was not aware of a way to remove it. He said you have to pull down the notifications menu, tap it, and then close it (essentially dialing and then ending the call).

I also had a look at the manual for the Galaxy Ace (GT-S5830). There is not much said in it about this (full manual, 127 pages, not a quick guide). They pretty much just tell you what voice mail is, how to set up voice mail server and listen to voice mails.

> In Idle mode, open the application list and select (phone icon),
>   Keypad and then tap and hold 1. Follow the instructions from the voice
>   mail server. You must save the voice mail server number before
>   accessing the server.

They don't even tell you how to clear the notification bar. They seem to be expecting that the user will know this by logic. Most manufacturers of Android handsets seem to be under the impression that Android is intuitive enough that they don't need to say many words about it in the manuals. Some manufacturers have more proper manuals, thoroughly explaining every detail, while some will just have quick guides.

I'm sorry I couldn't be of any more help to you.

May I ask why these notifications about voice mail bother you so much? Are you using voice mail? If you are not using it, then there is always the option to disable it, and you won't be getting any more of those.

So here are the options you have.

- Tap to listen

  You can tap the "new voice mail" icon from the notification bar to dial your voice mail inbox and listen to your voice mails.
- Ignore it

  You can always just ignore the icon.
- Disable voice mail

  If you are not using voice mail, or if you are not using it frequently you always have the option to disable it.
- Upgrade to Android 4.2

  If possible, you could try upgrading to Android 4.2. That requires rooting your phone and installing a custom ROM.
- Get a new phone

  This is the least wanted option for several reasons, the expense being usually number one. But sometimes it is the best and quickest solution that allows you to get on with your life and worry less about problems with technology. I would personally not change my phone just to get around this type of issue.

  Make sure you thoroughly test your new phone so you know it does what you want. It's usually not possible to test every feature in the store, you need to take it home and test it properly. Some carriers will allow you to bring the phone home and test both the phone and the service for 14 days, without commitment or signing any contract. My carrier (Tele2) has this option.

**How to disable voice mail on Galaxy Ace**

1. In Idle mode, open the application list and select
   Settings.
2. Select Call settings.
3. Select Voice mail number
4. Remove the number and save changes. If it doesn't allow you to leave it empty then type in some bogus (fake) number like +1 123456789 and save.

There is also the option "Voicemail service". See if you can just disable the service that way, instead of messing with numbers. It doesn't say in the manual what options you have, so you need to see for yourself.

*Note!*

*You can always continue using your voice mail. It's just that you won't be getting these annoying messages every time you get a voice mail. All you have to do in the future is just call the number for your voice mail inbox. You can just save that as a new contact and call it to check for new voice mails.*

Comment: wow, I will see when that happens again if what you say works

Comment: Okay. The first three options will always work. You can tap to listen, or ignore it, or disable voice mail altogether. The option to upgrade to Android 4.x is tricky, leave that as the last resort. Yeah, you can also try to press and hold to see if you get any menu. Don't be afraid to mess around with it, you own it. With these Android handsets, more often than not, there are hidden (secret) options and key combinations that are not even mentioned in the manual. I hope you will find a working solution.

Comment: Here's some reading on [4.2.2](http://au.ibtimes.com/articles/466841/20130511/update-samsung-galaxy-ace-android-4-2.htm#.UaMlw8rKTcf) upgrades. The mentioned Maclaw Studio release can be downloaded [here](http://maclaw.pl/downloads/). It looks like there's also a Cyanogen 10.1 release for Ace. You can find all the device-specific posts about the Ace at XDA [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=1164). If you decide to flash, make sure it's for the S5830 (if that's what you have).

Comment: You also have a great resource for all things Samssung over at [SamMobile](http://www.sammobile.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?f=63). Should you decide to try flashing a custom ROM.

Comment: So you just reboot the phone?... is that what you're saying?

Comment: Well, that's good to know. But it's too bad they didn't make any kind of option to clear it without having to reboot the phone just to clear out some annoying notifications. That's just lame on part of Samsung. Thanks for the update though.

Answer (score 0):

On **Android 4.x+** you should just be able to swipe it to the right to dismiss it.

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: This only works for phones running Android 4.0 and newer unless it's included in the rom.

Comment: Good point. Edited.

Comment: The Galaxy Ace GT comes with Android 2.3 and can be upgraded to Android 2.3.6.

Answer (score 0):

If your device is running Android 4.3 (Jelly Bean) or higher, [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appsropos.clearnotifications) app seems to be able to clear them.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All you've got to do is hold it down, go to app info, untick and retick 'show notifications' and then it should stay off the notification bar after reclicking it